# Hot to use shinyjs to get the id of a clickable <div> element?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, attributes, shinyjs

I'm making a ShinyApp that uses plain HTML to order clickable `<div>` sub-elements inside another `<div>` element.

I want the click event on the sub-elements to trigger a `reactiveVal()` in my server logic. I could do so by using `shinyjs::onclick("<div>.id", reactiveVal(id))`, but I would appreciate a better way of using the `.id` attribute of my `sub<div>` to directly modify my `reactiveVal()`, hopefully saving my from writting 118 `onclick()`s...

Below is the MWE of what I tried so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      2, offset = 1, h3('List of elements:'),
      HTML(
        '<div class = "periodic-table">
            <div class = "element" style = "cursor: pointer;" id = "Hydrogen"> Hydrogen </div>
            <div class = "element" style = "cursor: pointer;" id = "Helium"> Helium </div>
            <div class = "element" style = "cursor: pointer;" id = "Lithium"> Lithium </div>
            ... <br> (115 more chemical elements)
         </div>'
      )
    ),
    column(2, h3('Selected element:'), textOutput('SelectedElem'))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session, devMode = TRUE) {
  SelectedElem <- reactiveVal()
  
  onclick("Hydrogen", SelectedElem("Hydrogen"))
  onclick("Helium", SelectedElem("Helium"))
  onclick("Lithium", SelectedElem("Lithium"))
  
  output$SelectedElem <- renderText(SelectedElem())
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, enableBookmarking = "URL")
```

Desired behaviour:

> [image: GIF of the working app]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, what you want to do is add an event listener to each of these `div`s that will update a common input. This can be accomplished with the `javascrip` function `Shiny.onInputChange`([documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-send-message.html)).

There are multiple ways to add the event listener but this is one approach. In a separate file (in this case I'll use "www/sendID.js"):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element')
  
  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => Shiny.onInputChange("selected", element.id))
  })
  
})
```

Then update your UI to include this script:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      2, offset = 1, h3('List of elements:'),
      HTML(
        '<div class = "periodic-table">
            <div class = "element" style = "cursor: pointer;" id = "Hydrogen"> Hydrogen </div>
            <div class = "element" style = "cursor: pointer;" id = "Helium"> Helium </div>
            <div class = "element" style = "cursor: pointer;" id = "Lithium"> Lithium </div>
            ... <br> (115 more chemical elements)
         </div>'
      )
    ),
    column(2, h3('Selected element:'), textOutput('SelectedElem'))
  ),
  includeScript("www/sendID.js")
)
```

Then in the server you will only need to listen for a single `input`

```r
server <- function(input, output, session, devMode = TRUE) {  
  output$SelectedElem <- renderText(input$selected)
}
```

Comment: FYI you don't even need `shinyjs`

Comment: I would recommend using `Shiny.setInputValue()` instead of `Shiny.onInputChanged()` for better readability. These functions are aliases - see [this article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html)

Comment: I always forget which is the more recent alias. My Google search came up with the earlier article, but agree `Shiny.setInputValue()` is more clear naming